# How to time fish prompt

Tags: shell, terminal, fish

I'm considering switching from zsh to fish, however before I do I want to compare the speeds at which the prompts load.
I have a ZSH function which would time 10 times how long it would take for the prompt to load.

```
timeshell() {
  shell=${1-$SHELL}
  for i in $(seq 1 10); do /usr/bin/time $shell -i -c exit; done
}
```

I'm struggling to implement the same code into something fish compliant.
for instance the following:

```
time for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; fish; end
```

Wil actually load the fish shell prompt, cancelling the command.

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fish; but obviously your attempt starts an interactive shell which then waits for commands, and only exits when you tell it to.

Comment: This isn't timing the _prompt_ per se, it's timing how long the shell takes to start running. That really depends on how many config files the shell needs to execute before showing the prompt, and what those config files do. For me, judging the speed of a shell is how fast it is to do tab completion, autocompletion, command history, etc. That is to say, how fast it _feels_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand.
Is this what you mean?

```
function timeshell 
  set shell $SHELL
  for i in (seq 1 10); /usr/bin/time $shell -i -c exit; end
end
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, on the second line I need to set shell fish rather than $SHELL, otherwise it's timing zsh. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Within fish, you can time a function:

```
> time fish_prompt
Executed in    6.71 ms    fish       external
   usr time    1.72 ms    0.00 ms    1.72 ms
   sys time    6.07 ms    6.07 ms    0.00 ms
```